# Setting frame of IMU message in Gazebo Fortress

Tags: ros2, imu, gazebo-ignition, ignition-fortress

I am trying to setup a robot in Gazebo Fortress, under ROS2 Humble in Ubuntu 22.04.
This robot has 6 wheels, a lidar and an IMU. I have setup the xacro files and I am able to spawn the robot into Gazebo and get laser and IMU readings.

However, the frame of the IMU messages is not correct. This is my IMU gazebo code in its corresponding xacro file:

```
    <gazebo reference="${prefix}_${imu_name}">
        <material>Gazebo/Black</material>
        <gravity>true</gravity>
        <sensor name="${prefix}_imu_sensor" type="imu">
            <always_on>true</always_on>
            <update_rate>25</update_rate>
            <visualize>false</visualize>
            <topic>${prefix}/imu</topic>
            <plugin filename="libignition-gazebo-imu-system.so" name="ignition::gazebo::systems::Imu">
            </plugin>
            <pose>0 0 0 0 0 0</pose>
        </sensor>
    </gazebo>
```

I have tried to add `frameID` to the plugin parameters, as I did in Gazebo Classic, but it didn't work. My questions are:

1. How to change the frame published in the messages?
2. What parameters are available for the IMU plugin? Is there any documentation or where can I read the source code?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the source code it appears you can use the tag `gz_frame_id` or the older `ignition_frame_id` (deprecated) as a child of the `sensor` tag.

The relevant source code is [here](https://github.com/gazebosim/gz-sensors/blob/ec52913e608ce8f64053650bfcced84a70ca12e2/src/Sensor.cc#L158).

Answer (score 0):

Note: I am not able to comment, so I am writing in an answer section.

I am not sure if this might be helpful to you or not, but some of the resource are here.

Here is the header file for the imu sensor:
https://github.com/gazebosim/gz-sensors/blob/ign-sensors6/include/gz/sensors/ImuSensor.hh

You can find the source code for the imu sensors here:
https://github.com/gazebosim/gz-sensors/blob/ign-sensors6/src/ImuSensor.cc

example of imu sensor in sdf file:
https://github.com/gazebosim/gz-sim/blob/ign-gazebo6/examples/worlds/sensors.sdf

Comment: Thank you.  I will look through it, see if I learn how to do sensor plugins, although it seems the accepted answer is simpler.